# Button stop working since adding AjaxToolkit:ScriptManager

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, postback

I have recently added a AjaxToolkit:ScriptManager to my pages to use the CalenderExtender that they provide, since doing this none of my buttons have been hitting there events server side.

I have added a breakpoint on my methods and the corresponding method for the button is not getting hit and im wondering if it is because of the ScriptManager.

I have tried adding `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` to the button and sill does not working and also adding `EnablePageMethods="true"` to the ScriptManager.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sct1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Here is an example button:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="AddDepartments" runat="server" class="AddDepartments">
        <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lbl_adddepartmentadmin" runat="server" Text="Add Department:" CssClass="applicationfont" />
              <input id="txt_adddepartmentadmin" runat="server" type="text" class="smallinputbox" />
              <asp:Button id="btn_adddepartmentadmin" runat="server" CssClass="Button" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_adddepartmentadmin_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the code behind he event:

```
        protected void btn_adddepartmentadmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_adddepartmentadmin.Value == "" || txt_adddepartmentadmin.Value == null)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", "alert('Please enter a valid department name.');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            string returnResult = wsP.AddDepartment(new wsPersonnel.DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS { DEPARTMENT_NAME = txt_adddepartmentadmin.Value });

            if (returnResult == "Unsuccessful")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", "alert('That department already exists, please enter a unique name.');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", "alert('Department added.');", true);
                txt_adddepartmentadmin.Value = "";
                departmentamended = true;
                PopulateDepartments();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add more details? Like the relevant code for example

Comment: @Leo I would have to add all my code as its all my buttons that have stoped working ill add the code for the script manager.

Comment: how are you wiring up your event handlers? Can you show at leat ONE button?

Comment: @Leo I have added a button, just tested without the AJAXTOOlKIT and put the ASP:SCRIPTMANAGER there and it working so it is to do with the ajax toolkit.